# Sorting user input by alphabetical order in UNIX/Bash script

Tags: bash, unix, conditional-statements

Im creating a program in Unix where I take three inputs from a user (more specifically, 3 first names) and I need to output them alphabetically. I have a nested conditional but its not working and I have tried a lot of variations but Im not sure what Im missing... Heres what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a friend's name: "
read n1

echo -n "Enter another friend's name: "
read n2

echo -n "Enter a third friend's name: "
read n3


if [[ $n1 < $n2 ]]
then
    if [[ $n3 < $n1 ]]
    then
        echo $n3 $n1 $n2
    elif [[ $n3 < $n2 ]]
    then
        echo $n1 $n3 $n2
    else
        echo $n1 $n2 $n3
    fi
fi

if [[ $n1 < $n3 ]]
then
    if [[ $n2 < $n1 ]]
    then
        echo $n2 $n1 $n3
    elif [[ $n3 < $n2 ]]
    then
        echo $n3 $n2 $n1
    else
        echo $n2 $n3 $n1
    fi
fi
```

I believe my issue comes from the fact that when I input a name that is, for example, Zoe at first, it gets messed up.

thanks

Comment: sort and convert back to single line: `printf "%s\n" "$n1" "$n2" "$n3" | sort | tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 0):

As people have pointed out in the comments, using `sort` would probably be a better way to do this; but let me take a look at what's wrong with the current code.

The basic problem is that you have two separate `if` blocks:

```
if [[ $n1 < $n2 ]]
    ...

if [[ $n1 < $n3 ]]
    ...
```

So if neither condition is true (that is if `$n1` comes after both `$n2` and `$n3`, i.e. the order is CBA or CAB), then both `if` blocks get skipped and nothing gets printed.

Another problem is that if *both* conditions are true (that is if `$n1` comes *before* both `$n2` and `$n3`, i.e. the order is ABC or ACB), then both `if` blocks will run. So it will print the answer twice (except the second one will actually get it wrong).

The solution is to make your main conditions a single `if ... elif ... else ...` so that *exactly one* of the blocks will execute. You also need to keep careful track of which possible conditions lead to which parts of the code, so you handle each condition (i.e. each possible order of the names) in the right place. Something like this:

```
if [[ $n1 < $n2 ]]
    ...code with more ifs to handle ABC, ACB, and BCA

elif [[ $n1 < $n3 ]]
    # Note: to reach this point, [[ $n1 < $n2 ]] must be false
    # AND [[ $n1 < $n3 ]] must be true
    ...code that handles BAC ('cause that's the only case that gets here)

elif [[ $n2 < $n3 ]]
    # Note: to reach this point, [[ $n1 < $n2 ]] and [[ $n1 < $n3 ]]
    # must both be false, AND [[ $n2 < $n3 ]] must be true
    ...code that handles CAB

else
    # Note: to reach this point, ALL of the previous tests
    # must be false
    ...code that handles CBA
```

You could also organize it in a more symmetric way:

```
if [[ $n1 < $n2 ]]
    ...code with more ifs to handle ABC, ACB, and BCA

else
    ...code with more ifs to handle BAC, CAB, and CBA
```